# How to find out a String is an non-digit Integer number?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to found out if a given String is a pure Integer number, that means it is no double and no float .

What I have tried is a regular expression:

```
@"^\d+$"

if (Regex.IsMatch(oStreamDataValues[i].ToString(), @"^\d+$") == false)
```

That works fine but only until a String contains a number like 0.00 or any other digit value.

Comment: The concept of Integer is interesting... What do you mean, `int` as in C# `int`, or simply non-decimal? Are hex numbers ok? And negative ones?

Comment: yep it won't match `0.0`

Comment: int.TryParse not an option?

Comment: just to clarify: you want `"0.00"` to be accepted or not?

Comment: @xanatos I mean only non-decimal numbers

Comment: For example, do you want `12.0` to be considered an integer?

Comment: @BlackFrog no way i only need 'complete' Integer without any decimal values

Comment: That question is no duplicate i have seen it there is nothing about Integer..

Comment: @ArturKaraev just use the regex I gave in my post at the bottom of this thread.

Comment: Do you need to detect negative numbers also ?

Comment: @ArturKaraev other than the accepted answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just try to parse it using [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string s = "-12";

int i;
bool isInt = int.TryParse(s, out i);
```

If you also want to parse `0.00`:

```
bool isInt;

decimal d;

if (decimal.TryParse(s, out d))
{
    if (d % 1 == 0)
    {
        isInt = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isInt = false;
    }
}
else
{
    isInt = false;
}
```

Comment: same comment as with @chresse - will this parse `"0.00"`?

Comment: @CarstenKönig: It does now

Comment: @PatrickHofman, thank's that also works i gave you a upvote, just earned the privilege ;)

Comment: @ArturKaraev: Thanks. Glad it was useful to you :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `TryParse` method:

```
int value;
if(int.TryParse(myString, out value)) {
    // it is an integer
}
```

Comment: will try parse succeed with `"0.00"` - seems like the OP wants it to

Comment: I think he wants `"0.00"` to be accepted, but `"0.10"` not - the thing is: we don't know - and only accept negatives in addition to what the OP already has

Comment: what i want are only non-digit numbers, thank's chresse i will try it and give a reputation

Comment: @CarstenKönig No i dont want anything like 0.10 or 0.00 only whole numbers like 1 or 2 or 100221 :)

Comment: @ArturKaraev: `0.00` is a whole number.

Comment: @PatrickHofman LOL yes it is a whole number but i dont think c# will recognize 0.00 as a whole number too...

Comment: The solution is quite simple..   int intvalue;
                    double doublevalue;
                    if (int.TryParse(oStreamDataValues[i].ToString(), out intvalue))
                    {
                        oDataRow[i] = intvalue;
                    }
                    else if (double.TryParse(oStreamDataValues[i].ToString(), out doublevalue))
                    {
                        oDataRow[i] = doublevalue;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        oDataRow[i] = oStreamDataValues[i].ToString();
                    }

Comment: @ArturKaraev: You mean hybris' answer? Also, I don't know how that answers your question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman oh sorry i didnt see your code.. just too much answers here but i finally did it by using the TryParse method in different if-cases ;)

Comment: @ArturKaraev: Well, give my second code block a try, will you?

Comment: @PatrickHofman no, i just took chreese's code as a example which directed me on the right way

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, some *floating point values* are *positive examples* in your case

```
  4.00 // <- just 4
  1e3  // <- is 1000
 1e100 // <- 10...0 (100 zeros)
```

So I suggest parsing it into `Double`, and then test if fractional part is 0:

```
  String s = "123.0";

  Double v;

  if (Double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out v))
    if ((v - Math.Truncate(v)) < Math.Abs(v) / 1.0e20) //TODO: Adjast tolerance here
      Console.Write("this is an integer value");
```

Comment: Why use double which is imprecise? Why not use `decimal` like in my answer?

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: I've opted `Double` instead of `Decimal` in order to be able to work with numbers like `1e100`. If initial string values fall into `Decimal` range your answer is preferable.

Comment: Great, best answer here!

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly would use Int32 static methods to parse the String.
There is TryParse and Parse (depends if you want to use a try/catch or not).

```
int returnedNumber = 0;
if(!Int32.TryParse(oStreamDataValues[i].ToString(), out returnedNumber)) {
    //enter code here
}
```

or

```
bool isInt = true;
int returnedNumber = 0;
try {
    returnedNumber = Int32.Parse(oStreamDataValues[i].ToString());
}
catch(FormatException) {
    isInt = false;
}
if(!isInt) {
    //enter code here
}
```

### Parse method uses the following format :

The s parameter contains a number of the form:

[ws][sign]digits[ws] 
Items in square brackets ([ and ]) are optional. The following table describes each element.

ws Optional white space.
sign An optional sign.
digits A sequence of digits ranging from 0 to 9.

### References :

Parse : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
TryParse : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx